# C#: Output Current User / IP / Computer Name etc... to labels

Tags: c#, label, output, system, info

Im fairly new to c# and learning more daily though im stuck with this and can't find anything similar

On form load i would like to display:
* Current windows user
* Current IP 
* Hostname

And other system info directly into labels. Any pointers to where i can learn how do this or an example

Much appreciated

Comment: Did you even try to find answers to these one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

All these answers came from existing StackOverflow posts. You really should try a little harder.

Current user:

```
  string userName = 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
 labelName.Text = userName;
```

Current IP:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        return ip.ToString();
    }
}
throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
}

labelName.Text = GetLocalIPAddress();
```

Hostname:

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

labelName.Text = hostName;
```

Comment: Thanks both. I did search but could only find output to CMD.

Comment: @azza452 - Here's a tip - use search terms starting with C#, like: c# current ip address, or C# hostname. You'll usually get what you're looking for in the first few Google hits.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this class over the years to get some basic machine information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace STUFF
{
    public static class WorkStation
    {
        public const ulong MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        public const ulong GIGABYTE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

        #region MEMORYSTATUSEX
        /// <summary>
        /// contains information about the current state of both physical and virtual memory, including extended memory
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public class MEMORYSTATUSEX
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Size of the structure, in bytes. You must set this member before calling GlobalMemoryStatusEx.
            /// </summary>
            public uint dwLength;

            /// <summary>
            /// Number between 0 and 100 that specifies the approximate percentage of physical memory that is in use (0 indicates no memory use and 100 indicates full memory use).
            /// </summary>
            public uint dwMemoryLoad;

            /// <summary>
            /// Total size of physical memory, in bytes.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullTotalPhys;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size of physical memory available, in bytes.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullAvailPhys;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size of the committed memory limit, in bytes. This is physical memory plus the size of the page file, minus a small overhead.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullTotalPageFile;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size of available memory to commit, in bytes. The limit is ullTotalPageFile.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullAvailPageFile;

            /// <summary>
            /// Total size of the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullTotalVirtual;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullAvailVirtual;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the extended portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.
            /// </summary>
            public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:MEMORYSTATUSEX"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
            {
                this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region GlobalMemoryStatusEx
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
        #endregion      

        #region GetSystemMetrics
        private const UInt16 SM_SERVERR2 = 89;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetSystemMetrics([In] UInt16 smIndex);
        #endregion

        public static List<string> GetCPUInfo()
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\cimv2");
            ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor");
            ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
            ManagementObjectCollection CollectionOfResults = Searcher.Get();

            res.Add(string.Format("{0} Processor(s)", Environment.ProcessorCount));
            foreach (ManagementObject CurrentObject in CollectionOfResults)
            {
                res.Add(CurrentObject["Name"].ToString());
            }

            return res;
        }

        public static List<string> GetDriveInfo()
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            DriveInfo[] dirs = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (DriveInfo dir in dirs)
            {
                if ((dir.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed) && (dir.IsReady == true))
                {
                    res.Add(string.Format("Size of {0}: {1} GB", dir.Name, ((ulong)dir.TotalSize / GIGABYTE).ToString()));
                    res.Add(string.Format("Total Free Space: {0} GB", ((ulong)dir.TotalFreeSpace / GIGABYTE).ToString()));
                    res.Add(string.Format("Available Free Space: {0} GB", ((ulong)dir.AvailableFreeSpace / GIGABYTE).ToString()));
                }
            }

            return res;
        }

        public static List<string> GetGlobalizationInfo()
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            RegionInfo regionInfo = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion;
            TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

            res.Add(string.Format("Culture: {0}", cultureInfo.EnglishName));
            res.Add(string.Format("Region: {0}", regionInfo.EnglishName));
            res.Add(string.Format("Time Zone: {0}", timeZoneInfo.Id));
            res.Add(string.Format("Daylight Savings Enabled: {0}", timeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime));
            res.Add(string.Format("In Daylight Savings: {0}", timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now)));

            return res;
        }

        public static List<string> GetMemoryStatus()
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            MEMORYSTATUSEX msx = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();

            try
            {
                GlobalMemoryStatusEx(msx);

                double total = Math.Round((double)msx.ullTotalPhys / GIGABYTE, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                double available = Math.Round((double)msx.ullAvailPhys / GIGABYTE, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                double inUse = Math.Round((double)(msx.ullTotalPhys - msx.ullAvailPhys) / GIGABYTE, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

                res.Add(string.Format("Memory Load: {0}", msx.dwMemoryLoad));
                res.Add(string.Format("Total Physical (GB): {0}", total));
                res.Add(string.Format("In use (GB): {0}", inUse));
                res.Add(string.Format("Available (GB): {0}", available));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return res;
        }

        public static MachineInformation GetMachineInformation()
        {
            MachineInformation mi = new MachineInformation();

            try
            {
                ManagementClass osClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in osClass.GetInstances())
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData prop in queryObj.Properties)
                    {
                        switch(prop.Name)
                        {
                            case "Caption":
                                mi.Caption = prop.Value.ToString();
                                break;
                            case "LastBootUpTime":
                                mi.LastBootUpTime = prop.Value.ToString();
                                break;
                            case "Locale":
                                mi.Locale = prop.Value.ToString();
                                break;
                            case "SerialNumber":
                                mi.SerialNumber = prop.Value.ToString();
                                break;
                            case "Version":
                                mi.Version = prop.Value.ToString();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
               // We don't care if this fails....info is not critical
            }

            return mi;
        }

        public static List<string> GetMacAddresses()
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
                {
                    byte[] macAddress = ni.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes();
                    if (macAddress.Length == 6)
                    {
                        if (macAddress[0] != 0 ||
                            macAddress[1] != 0 ||
                            macAddress[2] != 0 ||
                            macAddress[3] != 0 ||
                            macAddress[4] != 0 ||
                            macAddress[5] != 0)
                        {
                            res.Add(string.Format("{0:X2}:{1:X2}:{2:X2}:{3:X2}:{4:X2}:{5:X2}",
                                macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2],
                                macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return res;
        }
    }
}
```